# Which countries does this patent protect US20040035049

Tags: patent-applications

I wondered which countries this patent covers other than the US?

Regards

Brett

https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/us20040035049

Answer (score 1):

This is only a patent application, and confers no rights in the US or elsewhere. 
Using The Lens, we find that is has not converted into [any granted patent rights](https://www.lens.org/lens/patent/US_2004_0035049_A1) anywhere, nor has it other family members pending.  The inventor, [Sallie McLarty](https://www.lens.org/lens/search?inventor=MCLARTY%20SALLIE) has one other invention disclosure in our database, which also has not become a granted patent.

However, if you were to look at the citations of this application by others, you'd see there are at [least 10 patent documents](https://www.lens.org/lens/patent/US_2004_0035049_A1/citations#c/in) (including some grants) that have noted this application.  Worth reading to see if they cover similar inventions.